# Correct path, based on date-style (e.g /2016-01-10) in python script

Tags: python, date, path

I wrote an script such as below that checks the content of the newly created/modified folders in `PARENT_DIR` (in this example within last 45 minutes) and makes a copy of those folders on specified path at `MOVE_DIR`.

```
import os
from shutil import copytree 
from time import time

def mins_since_mod(fname):
"""Return time from last modification in minutes"""
return (time() - os.path.getmtime(fname)) / 60

PARENT_DIR = '/home/B/A/(..?)'
MOVE_DIR = '/home/A/Updated_Folders'

# Loop over files in PARENT_DIR
for fname in os.listdir(PARENT_DIR):
# If the file is a directory and was modified in last 45 minutes
     if os.path.isdir(fname) and mins_since_mod(fname) < 45:
       copytree(fname, MOVE_DIR) # move it to a new location
```

There's another script (which is out of our interest, but) creates and names new folders based on the date, from time to time (for example there are `/B/A/2015-12-10` , `/B/A/2015-12-25` , `/B/A/2016-01-11` , `/B/A/2016-01-12` etc.)

I'd like to choose only the folder that is created today (kind of dynamic naming for the path at `PARENT_DIR` e.g: `/2016-01-12` for today) and just make a copy of it at the destination. I don't want to check and enter the path every time manually and prefer it to be done automatically everyday. by just executing the script.

How am I supposed to address the `PARENT_DIR = '/home/B/A/(..?)'` in order to achieve this goal?

p.s: I was trying to use PARENT_DIR = '/home/B/A/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)' but it didn't work out...

any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with these changes:

```
import os
import datetime
from shutil import copytree
from shutil import move
from time import time


def mins_since_mod(fname):
"""Return time from last modification in minutes"""
return (time() - os.path.getmtime(fname)) / 60
today = datetime.date.today()
PARENT_DIR = '/home/B/A/'+str(today)
MOVE_DIR = '/home/B/A/BackMeUp'

# Loop over files in PARENT_DIR
for fname in os.listdir(PARENT_DIR):
# If the file is a directory and was modified in last 15 minutes
if os.path.isdir(fname) and mins_since_mod(fname) < 60:
   copytree(fname, MOVE_DIR) # move it to a new location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime module to have the current date : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

You can then append it to your filepath:

```
PARENT_DIR = 'home/B/A' + currentdate
```

Just make sure to convert the datetime object to a string before appending.

Comment: I added `PARENT_DIR = '/home/sina/Desktop/'+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` and also `import time` right after `import os` and did also `import datetime` but when I execute it I get this: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'strftime'`